# ArcGIS Online Not Accepting CSS for Transparency

Tags: arcgis-online, css

I am attempting to make the background of an element (timecontainer) transparent by using ArcGIS Online's custom CSS option.

The desired effect is seen below (note the semi transparent background):
[image]

Using inspector in Firefox, I was able to find the element (timecontainer)that needed to be adjusted (below).
[image]

The background-color should be changed to rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.41), as seen below.
[image]

Using a CSS editor, I drafted the following:

```
#timeContainer {
  width: 750px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://imagebackground");
}

.timeInfo .bg .fg .window-bottom-left {
  background-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.41);
}
```

I then copied and pasted that CSS into the Time App's custom CSS window.
[image]

But the background remained a solid, grey color.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/43264437/820534